# python code stuck without error message

Tags: python, linux, error-handling, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am running a continuous web-scraping Python 2.7 code on Linux mint, to download data from a website. The code uses beautifulsoup 4 and url library. When a new line of data is written to my local text file, the code will print some characters in the Shell so that I know the code is working fine.

The problem is that sometimes the code stops working without any error message. By looking at the Shell, there is no red lines show up, but the printing does not continue, so I know something went wrong. And this happens not frequently, approximately once a week.

My question is, how do i check if this problem is caused by my Python code or by the Linux mint system? Maybe there is a Linux bug in the I/O layer?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Does the code terminate? or does it keep on running?

Comment: Add more debug messages in other part of the code to see which part causes problem

Comment: @ap0, I don't mind post my code but it takes a few days to see the 'error' I mentioned if you run it.

Comment: @Ekwinder Saini, from the Shell, it looks the code did not terminate.

Comment: @tuananh, what exactly do you mean by  'add more debug messages in other part of the code'? I don't know debugging python very well.

Comment: For example, you can print a message before you visit a url, after you visit and before you parse, then after parse, ...

Comment: Use the `logging` module to write information to a rotating file handler. Sprinkle logging messages around and check that file when things go bad.

Comment: @tuananh, yes I did use something similar to track if my code is still running or not. The code print a message after a new line is written to a local text file. Do you mean the url parsing is more likely to be the problem?